# Then find the value of $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $\sum _{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n $ be the Laurent series in the expansion of $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2z^2-13z+15}$ in the annulus $\frac{3}{2}<|z|<5$ .

Then

> find the value of $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$.

IN order to find the value I will have to find Laurent series expansion of the function which is very tough.Is there any easy way to do it
?

Comment: Is it really that tough? It would definitely be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Hint: What about the roots of $2z^2-13z+15$ in relation to the annulus? And the expansion of the geometric series?

Answer (score 1):

Your series must be such that the following holds:

$$(2z^2-13z+15)\sum a_nz^n  = 1$$

$$\sum 2a_nz^{n+2} - \sum 13a_nz^{n+1} + \sum 15 a_n z^n = 1$$

Equate the coefficients of the LHS to the RHS and you can find all $a_n$. Do this with the equations that contains $a_1$ and $a_2$ and you should be able to find them

Also, since there is a simple pole in $z = 3/2$, there will be a term in $z^{-1}$ but you know all the other negative coefficients are $0$.

Comment: The function has a pole at $z=\frac32$, so there will be terms with negative exponents.

Comment: @TonyK thanks! I edited

Comment: My comment as originally posted was misleading (I have edited it). I think there are terms for all negative exponents, not just $z^{-1}$.

Comment: @TonyK why? isn't the pole of order 1?

Comment: For instance, $1/(z-1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{-n}$ for $|z| > 1$.

Comment: Why will $z=\frac{3}{2}$ be a pole ?it is not in the annulus ;if it is so then $z=5$ wll also be

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2z^2-13z+15}=\frac{1}{(z-5)(2z-3)}=\frac{1}{7}\left(\frac{1}{z-5}-\frac{2}{2z-3}\right)$

Now expand it in the given region.

Comment: I tried your suggestion

Comment: But I got $a_1=f^{'}(0)=\frac{91}{25\times 9};a_2=\frac{973}{27\times 125}$

Comment: which are nowhere near my answer ;can you please check and give some details

Comment: The above formula is correct. A new question about the expansion into a Laurent series has been posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634024/laurent-series-expansion-of-f.